# Moving from splash screen to another screen in a different folder android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screen

I currently have coded my splash screen and have it up and running, if I want to move to another screen in the class I am able to do so, however my login screen is located in a Database folder. Everytime I try and use an intent it underlines the login and saying it is not a valid constructor?

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you using activity or Fragment for moving the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate like this No matter where is your Login activity you just need to import the package.

Dont worry about it android studio will suggest you to import the package of Login activity.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
                        finish();

                    }
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Comment: Use of handlers and runnables to decide duration of Splash is not a good practice.

Comment: ohh i heared something new thanks . Can you please explain why ?? and wht does you use for splash ?

Comment: `Can you explain why?` on what basis do you decide that 3000ms? Sometimes you app may start in 100 milliseconds, and sometimes your may take 10,000 ms. So the best way is to perform all operation in `onCreate()` and call the new Activity in `onResume()` since onResume is called only when your activity is ready and this is the best way to know that your app is ready and UI can be shown to user.

Comment: Thank you so much i got your thing. So you are telling that i start that handler in onResume() right ?

Comment: No, you dont need handler at all. **Just start the activity in on resume without any handler or runnable**. Depending on the device speed and other factors, amount of time your splash screen will stay will be adjusted automatically

Comment: Okey but i dont have that time consuming task in splash and thats why by default i want to show splash screen for 3000ms to the user.

Comment: You are killing the user experience then. Apps like Whatsapp, facebook, ert have background tasks to do , so they use splash screen. If your app has nothing, even then you can add splash screen to hide initial white screen. But it doesnt mean that you have to show it for longer time. User prefer content, not the splash.

Answer (score 0):

Write the complete name of your class and then **ALT+Enter** on it , when underline appears, It will add import for your class, And your code will work.